# How to get Padding or margin value in relative value using jQuery

Tags: jquery

If I have an element with CSS style like code

```
td class="bogus" style="padding-left: 1em;"
```

how can I use jQuery to get `padding-left` value as 1em instead of pixels?

```
$(".bogus").css("padding-left");
```

This only returns the pixels, but I want it to return what's really in the code, in this case, relative value 1em instead. How ?

Thanks for any guide.

- Qu

Answer (score 8):

What you can do is to set the base font size (the font-size property on the `<body>` element) to around 62.8% (some say 62.5%):

```
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">
```

This makes the base font, or 1.0em, approximately equal to 10px. It's not exact, and changes from font to font, but generally speaking it's accurate enough. Having done that, you can use EMs and their pixel equivalents:

1.0em = 10px, 1.1em = 11px, 1.2em = 12px etc.

So you can easily convert from pixels to EMs, by dividing by 10:

```
var ems = parseInt($(".bogus").css("padding-left")) / 10;
```

Comment: Note: this will not work if the user has changed the default font size in their browser, or if the browser's default font size is something other than 16px (Safari).